# Initialization of non-const reference from an rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
int returnByValue()
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    const int &cref = returnByValue(); // case I
    int &ref = returnByValue(); // case II -- compilation error
    return 0;
}
```

A reference variable is an alias, that is, an alias for a value, then how case I has no error as value returned by returnByValue() is a rvalue an case II has a compilation error?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. A reference is not an alias for a variable. It is an alias for a *value*.

Comment: Yes, an alias for a value ("another name for an already existing variable" conveys the same info).

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem here?

Comment: _"('another name for an already existing variable' conveys the same info)"_ No, it doesn't; it conveys a subtly different, and incorrect, claim.

Comment: Okay understood. Can you help me understand as to how const reference can be assigned to rvalue? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @VishvajeetT: It's simply a language rule that says that const lvalue references can bind to rvalues. The reason for this is that it conveniently allows calling functions that don't modify their arguments with temporary values.

Comment: I don't understand your question title: Which part of this question is about a "non-const reference"?

Comment: @VishvajeetT: Because it can. This might be easier if you explain why you think it shouldn't.

Comment: Mistake on my side, question was incomplete @KerrekSB; Case II covers  non-const reference.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As rvalue is being assigned

Comment: @VishvajeetT: First of all, no it's not. And even if it were, rvalues can be assigned just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea behind references is that lvalue references bind to lvalues, and rvalue references bind to rvalues; the reference thus bound henceforth refers to the value it was bound to.

However, C++ makes one exception to this rule and allows *const* lvalue references to also bind to rvalues. The reason for this is mostly convenience: It allows functions with const lvalue reference parameters to be called with temporaries, and not just with lvalues:

```
void do_something(const ExpensiveType&);  // expects lvalue?

ExpensiveType make_one();

// ...

do_something(make_one());  // call with rvalue is OK, too!
```

Functions that are particularly fond of const-ref parameters are copy constructors and copy assignment operators; if those could only be invoked on lvalues, you would need a lot more boilerplate in your code.

This exception is only granted to *const* references, since functions with such parameters don't modify the arguments and only "read" them, if you will. By contrast, rvalue references are not allowed to bind to mutable lvalue references, because we expect the value to be modified through such references, and it would almost certainly be a programming error to modify something that's immediately destroyed. (But if you really needed to, you could write a user-defined rvalue-to-lvalue conversion.)